# Firebase iOS - Snapshot suddenly returning null when I know a value exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code that has been running fine for weeks suddenly is returning a null value when I call snapshot.value. Here is a picture of my DB:

[image]

My code is:

```
_ = ref.child("profiles").child((empID as!FIRDataSnapshot).value as! String).child("nickname").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

      print(snapshot)

      self.names.append((snapshot).value as! String)
})
```

When I print the ref that I'm trying to make the snapshot from, I copy and paste the link into my browser and it correctly takes me to this screen:

[image]

So I have no idea why when I print snapshot it says

```
Snap (nickname) <null>
```

when there clearly is a value there. Then it throws an exception in the line where I try to append the nickname to a list. Does anyone know how this is possible? Especially since I don't recall changing anything to do with this piece of code in weeks. While I did not change the code recently, the only thing I've done is upload my app to TestFlight and had a few people download, could that possibly cause any of this somehow? I doubt this is the case because my code retrieves a value from another snapshot before this particular call successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Try to add child empid as a string. You can cast it safely first with something like if let empid = empid as! String

Comment: Will this matter since when I put the ref's url in my browser it works? I will try it, thanks

Comment: I think the error is because you added as a child the value of empID, tell me if that works and I'll post it like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a different/better way to do this, but for your purposes, the following will work:

First, create a Profile model in a Profile.swift file, like so:

```
import UIKit

class Goal: NSObject {
    var nickname: String?
    var type: String?
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
let profiles = [Profile]()

ref.child("profiles").child(empID).observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            let profile = Profile()

            profile.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            for item in dictionary {

                if item.key == "nickname" {

                       print(item)
                       // do whatever logic you wanna do with item here - item will be set to the value of key "nickname"

                }
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: It would be great if someone could attempt to explain what the problem is and why this solution addresses it.  I have a similar issue, and can't for the life of me see how this answers why the original question's code returns null when there's clearly a value